# Keeping a database size down using unique fields with Django

Tags: django, django-models

I ran into a snag on a project today, and considering it's already got quite a bit of data entered, destruction and rebuilding is not a good option.  So here it is...  This is a site that is basically a helper tool for people learning Mandarin Chinese (for now).  A user keeps track of their phrases, vocab, grammar points.  Originally, I just set all three of these to be unique fields in that (for example) nobody can enter the same vocab twice.  For some reason, that change was either reverted or I did away with it.  I don't remember, and it's too late for back tracking now.  So my question here is, how can I change my model up so that one user can't make the same exact entry as another user?  And as a follow up, if a user does try and make a duplicate entry, I can give said user is given the option to view\modify that entry?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db import models
from random import randint

# Create your models here.

SOURCES = [
    ('DUOLINGO', 'Duolingo'),
    ('MEMRISE', 'Memrise'),
    ('CLASS', 'Class'),
    ('OTHER', 'Other'),
]

LEVELS = [
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 6),
]


######################################        ############################################


class RandomManager(models.Manager):
    ''' Pulls a random record from a model '''
    def random(self, user=None):
        max_id = self.aggregate(max_id=Count('id'))['max_id']
        random_index = randint(0, max_id - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]


####################################### Vocabs ############################################


class Vocabulary(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vocab = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    audio = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = RandomManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Chinese Vocabulary"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    # this function will be invoked when this model object is foreign key of other model(for example Employee model.).
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vocab


####################################### Phrases ############################################


class Phrases(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phrase = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    translation = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    audio = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, choices=SOURCES)
    objects = RandomManager()

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = "Chinese Phrases"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    # this function will be invoked when this model object is foreign key of other model(for example Employee model.).
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phrase


####################################### Grammar ############################################


class Grammar(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, choices=SOURCES)
    objects = RandomManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Grammar Point"
        verbose_name_plural = "Grammar Points"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


####################################### Dictionary ############################################


class Dictionary(models.Model):
    traditional = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    simplified = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pinyin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    simplified_radical = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hsk_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=LEVELS, default=0)
    frequency_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    phrase_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    radical_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    definition = models.TextField()
    objects = RandomManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Dictionary"
        verbose_name_plural = "Dictionary"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.simplified
```

Comment: which field in which model is supposed to be unique? You talk about "phrases, vocal and grammar points" but these are models, not fields.

Comment: In general, you would add `unique=True` to a field to enforce it being unique. Or use a `UniqueConstraint` if it needs to be unique together with another field. The issue here is that your models have a fk to one `User`, so how would you model multiple users sharing the same entries?

Comment: Also, before you can migrate your tables to have the new constraints, you will need to migrate your data to a point where you know your fields are unique (otherwise migration will fail), so you will need to write a data migration to remove duplicates.

Comment: The `RandomManager` has two problems: (a) in case all ids exists, it will never select the last values, and (b) if some `id`s are removed, then it is possible it will have an out of bounds.